# PYTHONPATH environment variable, not found

Tags: 14.04, python, django

I have recently updated ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and my PYTHONPATH has apparently been spoiled,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 17, in <module>
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I throw this error, for example when I try to run my project in DJANGO.
How can I rebuild the environment variable?

Comment: Did you forget to activate virtualenv?

Comment: If I have it activated

Comment: May be you have installed django for a different version of python (python 3?). Check the versions.

Comment: Virtualenv I have it installed for 2.7, but I also have 3.5, but by default I always have it 2.7, I do not think that's the problem.

Comment: @AlejandroHurtado when debugging problems it's important to check things, "thinking" it's not a problem won't lead you very far. So double check that Django is properly installed, probably through `pip`, in the same virtualenv you have activated. You also mention two Python versions, are those inside the same virtualenv?

Comment: excuse, 
I am working with Django10 in my virtualenv, I think the problem is the following, when I update ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, in the python 14 by default if I am not wrong I had version 2.7.6, and now by default it launches python 2.7.12 .